# Should one AWS Lambda write to multiple targets?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am relatively new to AWS and I have trouble understanding, if I am to properly design AWS Lambda for following scenario:

1. SQS message is being written into specific queue that AWS lambda is listening to and has trigger on it.
2. AWS lambda on read sqs message is passing it further into multiple targets like SNS/DynamoDB/another SQS query.

Is this design ok? Should I separate each target into separate AWS lambda or should they be a part of one?

What is the role of AWS lambda destinations in this? Should I create a separate destination for each of those amazon services or the purpose of AWS targets is different? (like processing success/failure scenarios?)

Not sure if it matters, but I am planning to write this solution using C# language.

Comment: The lambda function can do pretty much anything with the message retrieved from SQS queue. It can publish the message further to SNS, write to DynamoDB and publish the message to SQS in single operation. You want the lambda function to do all these three things with a single message?

Comment: Is the purpose of this initial Lambda simply to distribute a copy of the message to multiple targets (whether they be other Lambdas, SQS, SNS etc.)? Or does it actually do processing of the message (other than forwarding it)? If all it does it forward it then you should consider SNS as the original target for the message, rather than SQS, and have multiple subscribers (e.g. Lambda, SQS) to the SNS topic.

Comment: Only distributing, I was firstly considering using for that purpose SNS/Eventbridge, but as far as I see SNS natively doesn't support forwarding to DynamoDB and EventBridge was painful to make work done (not sure if it is possible?). Is there a benefit of using SNS then SQS on intial target, if I have to use Lambda to pass this message further anyway?

Comment: Nothing supports auto-forwarding to DynamoDB, that I know of. Why would it? You need an application to write data into a DynamoDB table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to have one lambda function that would trigger based on any SQS messages that you'll receive. Then you can process the message, and use the content to your use-case which you mentioned. Basically you'll receive an SQS event from your lambda function, once the trigger is invoked. What you have to do is to capture that event and process :

> SNS/DynamoDB/another SQS query

But make sure to have a mechanism, to delete the SQS message once you have processed it, so that you don't keep on reading or polling the old SQS messages repeatedly. You could read up on [DLQ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) (Dead-Letter-Queue), which could be useful. For your reference, have a look at [this](https://www.jeremydaly.com/serverless-consumers-with-lambda-and-sqs-triggers/) too so that you can get yourself started.

Comment: How should I pass information to what targets the lambda should write? Manually, in the code with all the configuration passing logic and so on? Or is there some other way of doing so for example via AWS lambda targets?

Comment: You mean, you want to do certain action based on the information you get? and that information is coming from SQS, correct?

Comment: I mean that should I specify somewhere in AWS console that those targets are going to be consumer from this lambda, or should everything be written manually, just like it would be a normal .net service.

Comment: You don't have to worry about deleting messages from SQS when using lambda triggers. [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).

Comment: @phoenix my understanding was, you were going to process the sqs message from your lambda and use that content to your other targets (SNS/DynamoDB/another SQS query). There should be API's for those aws services, just like what python has (boto3). So you can use those api's to invoke some of the methods appropriately to achieve the actions.